# Flash message not being displayed while rescuing from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

Looks like a bug with rails but want to make sure I didn't miss anything before reporting a bug.

I am trying to rescue from `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` in the application controller with the following code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken, with: :show_errors

  ....

  private

  def show_errors
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "Cookies are disabled"
  end
end
```

The redirect works fine, but the alert message does not show. The flash hash is empty in the new page: `#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007f9dbdb5c1d0 @discard=#<Set: {}>, @flashes={}, @now=nil>`

There are no other filters in the application controller that could be affecting the hash / causing another redirect. The logs show only one redirect as expected.

Tried `flash.keep[:alert] = ..` and `flash.now[:alert] = ..` as well; no luck.

Getting this behavior on two different rails apps, one with `4.2.0` and another with `4.1.6`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def show_errors
  flash[:error] = "Cookies are disabled"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Does not work. As I mentioned above, the entire flash hash is coming as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew White gave an explanation on what is happening on [the issue I created](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20035):

> Since flash is dependent on the session and the session is dependent
>   on cookies working then it's never going to work if you think about
>   it, :-)
>
> I'd suggest redirecting to a custom url or add a query param to the
>   url that triggers the display of the message.

I am redirecting to a custom url as suggested.